# Update values in nested object recursively in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, recursion, nested-object

We need to update the object in nested objects using recursion in typescript .Need to add extra properties to the object which is in a nested object . Nesting can change overtime and so recursion will only work
Below is the input data :

```
[
  {
    "headerName": "Group 1",
    "children": [
      {
        "field": "G1-C1"
      },
      {
        "field": "G1-C2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "headerName": "Group 2",
    "children": [
      {
        "headerName": "G2 - C1",
        "children": [
          {
            "field": "G2 - C1-C1"
          },
          {
            "field": "G2 - C1-C2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "field": "G2-C2"
      },
      {
        "field": "G2-C3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "headerName": "Group3",
    "children": [
      {
        "field": "G3-C1"
      },
      {
        "field": "G3-C2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

which needed to be transformed as :

```
[
  {
    "headerName": "Group 1",
    "children": [
      {
        "field": "G1-C1",
        "visible": true,
        "width": 200,
        "headerName": "Group1"
      },
      {
        "field": "G1-C2",
        "visible": true,
        "width": 200,
        "headerName": "Group1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "headerName": "Group 2",
    "children": [
      {
        "headerName": "G2 - C1",
        "children": [
          {
            "field": "G2 - C1-C1",
            "width": 200,
            "headerName": "Group2-C1"
          },
          {
            "field": "G2 - C1-C2",
            "width": 200,
            "headerName": "Group2-C1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "field": "G2-C2",
        "width": 200,
        "headerName": "Group2"
      },
      {
        "field": "G2-C3",
        "width": 200,
        "headerName": "Group2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "headerName": "Group3",
    "children": [
      {
        "field": "G3-C1",
        "width": 200,
        "headerName": "Group3"
      },
      {
        "field": "G3-C2",
        "width": 200,
        "headerName": "Group3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Tried several ways but was not able to find a way . It would be great help of there is any quick way to find a solution for this problem . This below method works but not sure if its is correct .

```
          formatData(columns: any) {     
            columns.forEach((i: any,index) => {
              if (i.hasOwnProperty('children')) {       
                this.formatData(i.children);
              } else {       
                columns[index] = {...{ field : i.field, headerName: 
                i.field, sortable: true, hide: false }};                    
              }      
            });            
          }
```

Comment: please provide at least one way you have tried

Comment: please provide your question with code example from your comment

Comment: I have updated my way of solution in question . it does work . but could you please verify it ... @captain-yossarian

Comment: I have provided you with type safe solution. I think `this.formatData` should also handle `headerName`. My solution handles it. Please check if my solution meets your requirements

Answer (score 0):

FIrst of all we need to define type of our data structure:

```js
type WithChildren = {
  headerName: string,
  children: DataStructure[]
}

type WithoutChildrenInput = {
  field: string,
}


type WithoutChildrenOutput = {
  field: string,
} & Pick<WithChildren, 'headerName'>

type DataStructure = WithChildren | WithoutChildrenInput

type DataStructureOutput = WithChildren | WithoutChildrenOutput
```

Then we can define our logic:

```js
const fieldOutput = (
  field: string,
  headerName: string
) => ({
  field,
  headerName,
  visible: true,
  width: 200,
})

const childrenOutput = (headerName: string, children: DataStructure[]) => (
  { headerName, children: builder(children, headerName) }
)

const withChildren = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: DataStructure)
  : obj is WithChildren =>
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, 'children');

const builder = (data: DataStructure[], headerName = ''): DataStructureOutput[] =>
  data.reduce<DataStructureOutput[]>((acc, elem) =>
    withChildren(elem)
      ? [...acc, childrenOutput(elem.headerName, elem.children)]
      : [...acc, fieldOutput(elem.field, headerName)], [])

const result = builder(data)
```

I have created two helpers: `childrenOutput` and `fieldOutput`.

**`fieldOutput`** - just creates a plain object of field entity. nothing special

**`childrenOutput`** - generates expected data structure with children and calls under the hood `builder` function.

**`withChildren`** - is a [user defined typeguard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) which helps narrow the type

You may think that it is a bad practice to call function before you define it. You can declare `builder` with `function` keyword or pass third argument to `childrenOutput` like here:

```js
const childrenOutput = (headerName: string, children: DataStructure[], callback: (data: DataStructure[], headerName: string) => DataStructureOutput[]) => (
  { headerName, children: builder(children, headerName) }
)
```

It is up to you.

Whole code:

```js
type WithChildren = {
  headerName: string,
  children: DataStructure[]
}

type WithoutChildrenInput = {
  field: string,
}


type WithoutChildrenOutput = {
  field: string,
} & Pick<WithChildren, 'headerName'>

type DataStructure = WithChildren | WithoutChildrenInput

type DataStructureOutput = WithChildren | WithoutChildrenOutput

const data: DataStructure[] = [
  {
    "headerName": "Group 1",
    "children": [
      {
        "field": "G1-C1"
      },
      {
        "field": "G1-C2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "headerName": "Group 2",
    "children": [
      {
        "headerName": "G2 - C1",
        "children": [
          {
            "field": "G2 - C1-C1"
          },
          {
            "field": "G2 - C1-C2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "field": "G2-C2"
      },
      {
        "field": "G2-C3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "headerName": "Group3",
    "children": [
      {
        "field": "G3-C1"
      },
      {
        "field": "G3-C2"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const fieldOutput = (
  field: string,
  headerName: string
) => ({
  field,
  headerName,
  visible: true,
  width: 200,
})

const childrenOutput = (headerName: string, children: DataStructure[], callback: (data: DataStructure[], headerName: string) => DataStructureOutput[]) => (
  { headerName, children: builder(children, headerName) }
)

const withChildren = <Obj, Prop extends string>(obj: DataStructure)
  : obj is WithChildren =>
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, 'children');

const builder = (data: DataStructure[], headerName = ''): DataStructureOutput[] =>
  data.reduce<DataStructureOutput[]>((acc, elem) =>
    withChildren(elem)
      ? [...acc, childrenOutput(elem.headerName, elem.children, builder)]
      : [...acc, fieldOutput(elem.field, headerName)], [])

const result = builder(data)

console.log({ result })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIHUCWoAWBhFiA2ATATtAHawC8sA3sLLCtAIY7R4BydAttAFywDOoeiQgHMANFVgBjTLgKFuAETqg6AZX4BXCaHUEA2gF1gAXxAQYCZCgD260Bmz4iASUKRbpCuIBmiaLm58AsJiJqZQcEioNnbSjoQA8rZuoB6U1D5%20OAH8gqLGsABksAAKiBIA1gA8keixsiKwAOS0DEysHI0AfGHmispqeJraBB419jJEsAA%20FlG243EuyT1wfaoaWjrQiaDJo5YLstOz1vN1RDvLwBJWhHywOEp0Ck8DQ1sGHrriadSwAEQtRgsdjQf7cf4AcTwNkgsAAjP8xH8AVIHLJwbBvijqL8cQCMrhMVD4QBaNCI8QoozInF4nH-Qk4YmQsloABM-ypfxMKMM1BpP25gPowPaYIh0NhsE5tOo-zRE0ImOxdO5KJFrRBHBZ7NgpNgFKR6r%20CvOyu4qvxuJN%20MZviJkr1Bop5Mp1p5cut9I99syuv1hrZnNtPND-JxgvxPtNTN15JD%20Kjat9cad5IAzFyk9yI8n6ZqxaCWTD1JAs16zeiiCqTTH5WmAZCM27s5GvTbUw7mZKWxy29Tc%20ITIZrrd7kzLu4yAAKbzd7JBPLUIFtUGL3LAACUpE6sBnvyZtNX2ugtIAbogeIgAEZYLiwDRn8QAd0QOFQ3HZAAZvyEtyANx3CkipxFOKSzie4obsEkjmi8-QbMM0AGA0Eh0FgWA3nQFTcDOjzKAh6yDJsej6A0UHrrwOTCDuJB7msbykdsSS2AYdF7nOuI0KKa4cGh8GwDe6gOEwM6gfUPFauKO4mABY7AbAb6oIckxkJU8Q3gAVg0xQwnC0AAB6gEQOA8NRS6dDOVjaURTHIQB1DcDZWmwFeJyqcQ9HiJpWnQFoAB0kAwqAVhmNAAUoHQPDxC%20hB6VYMB4BAAXoZh1naQ0jQSUQjRbgA3IB44pMJol4B4%20FPHZSEfORUlFhwHiNHl1Ukch4GfN51AEXQAUEDgmjQJUjE1QQHX6FZM44RIDR%20NAbAcdyym1NWhAznNC0mgA-FiAV7dNAmreB633mwkW8aes2nal5oNKVuBMFuEYopae0BQdsCTqxoAnfNAVHvVfHQE9DTsUVikEDw6hYBBQkiQ9eCVco8lATwVj3gFWBWEIB6wJD0MpEYW5AA)